What happens if your flight is cancelled on the last day of your visa; does it vary by country/region?
The question My cancelled flight caused me to overstay my visa and now my visa application was rejected and its answer are most informative! (it asks specifically what happens when you overstay in Schengen (Europe) visa area).
Important part of the answer:

A visa extension can be considered ... in the case of force majeure. Example: No air traffic due to weather conditions or strike

This question is similar but I hope to learn if this strict, but common sense approach is generally true, that is, can we sensibly assume it applies to most/all other areas of the world too?
Unimportant note
In case it's of interest, I have a flight 3 hours before midnight on the last day of my visa in Thailand, so if there's any significant delay, I'll have overstayed my visa. But rather than looking up this specific country's policies, I wonder if I can apply the general principle of expecting them to be "strict, but have common sense" as per the answer in the case of the Schengen area, that is, can we assume this principle to apply to every other country too, or is it more the case that countries differ significantly in their principles and therefore you cannot generalise, but have to look them up individually.

This is why we usually advice not to plan to the last day/minute of your visa and why short term visa often have one or two days extra above what is asked for, if not always.

@Willeke would you believe it, what you suggest is exactly what would (and should) have happened. But weary after a 9h flight, and put on the spot at a busy immigration queue, I blurted out “three weeks” instead of “four weeks”. Why? There is no good answer; a bizarre and silly mistake probably in part because I was still waking up.

In that case it is about a visa on entry, not about a visa applied for weeks in advance, which might have its own set of exceptions.

@Willeke oh wow, I had no idea the two types of visas were treated any differently (I had assumed policies for overstaying would be the same irrespective of visa type for that country).

@Willeke I think you’ve partly answered my question, since if it cannot be assumed visas of the same country will be treated similarly, I suspect it’s a stretch to imagine that visas of different countries would be?

I would say that most countries have a force majeure concept, but the approach to actually invoking it will likely vary by country and immigration status, and the reason. Flights routinely get cancelled. Trying to claim force majeure when eg an overstay could have been avoided simply by booking a flight a few days before the deadline may not work in many cases IMHO

"Strict, but have common sense" doesn't really help you here, IMO. If anything, it backfires, because it applies to yourself too: common sense says you leave some buffer before the end of your visa if at all possible, precisely to prevent typical last-minute changes from causing you to break the law.

The key point about the question you linked is that the asker took no steps to renew their visa. If your flight is cancelled and you will need to overstay, you need to contact the authorities immediately.

@JackAidley would the authorities be the immigration/visa department at the airport?

@stevec: I don't know who would be the best point of contact, it probably depends where you are when the cancellation comes through, and probably varies by country.

@Willeke they don't always have extra days for sure. I've been issued visas in the past that are were exactly as long as my intended travel (8 days etc). The passport police was counting fingers on my way out!

@stevec (for thailand) When I had to get a visa extension inside thailand (not at the airport), I was told by other people waiting in line that the immigration staff can be fairly corrupt, and indeed when I went in there was a bunch of "gifts" in the shape of food etc. I would not expect a perfectly above-the-board treatment if you overstay and then try to not get an overstay stamp and associated fine. (I was recommended to overstay instead of getting a visa extension by some people for the record, esp as visa extension cost more than the fine for 3 days, but I got a visa extension anyways)

@ave, I did not say always, but it does happen.

@Willeke What you write is nonsense. Countries that are so particularly fond of punishing visitors for staying 5 days while their visa says 4 days are mostly the same identical countries as those requiring visitors to buy air tickets in advance and to include them in the visa application. And they base the validity of their visas on the dates of those tickets.

Same question but specific to the USA: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109991/what-happens-if-im-forced-to-overstay-in-the-u-s-because-my-flight-is-delayed

I don't think there is a "one size fits all" answer here. This will depend on the airline, the country, the type of Visa and partially on the mood of the officers that ran into it.

I have a flight 3 hours before midnight on the last day of my visa in Thailand, so if there's any significant delay, I'll have overstayed my visa.

Maybe. Its worth checking what exactly constitutes your time of "leaving the country". I would think the most practical definition would be when you show up at exit immigration and an officer looks at your papers as that's the point they have to look at your stuff anyway. Any other time options (scheduled departure, actual gate closing time, lift off time, leaving Thai airspace, etc) would be more complicated and there is no benefit for them doing so.
So chances are as long as you show you in in exit immigration before your Visa expires, you will be fine. Of course, that doesn't help if they don't allow you to check in before midnight in the first place: you need a boarding pass to get to exit immigration. If the airline will NOT give a boarding pass before your Visa expiration you should contact them and lean in hard for information and support. They typically know what happens at this specific airport and country.
Here is one example how this can play out. We were departing Beijing. The incoming plane was diverted because of heavy smog, the crew timed out before they were able to get the plane to Beijing and the flight was moved to the next day. At this point most passengers had checked in and were in the departure area. Many passengers only had a single-entry Visa which already head been invalidated in exit immigration, so they weren't allowed to re-enter the country for the night.
Turns out they had a process for this: Everybody got stamped a emergency/transit/short time Visa into their passport. They then herded  into a bus and drove us to a hotel. We were allowed to roam around in the hotel but not leave the general premises, so we were "sort of" in China proper. Next day the process happened in reverse and we finally departed (albeit 28 hours late).

The 'because of heavy smog' is a Force majeure situation. 'any significant delay' of the flight is not. The first is often caused by 'Mother Nature' ('when an extraordinary event or circumstance beyond the control of the parties'), whereas anything caused by one of the contract parties is not. Delays of flights is, afterall, an everyday occurrence.

Since it is, solely the travelers responsibility (other than in a force majeure situation) to insure that they conform to the relevant immigration laws that, any delay caused by the airline in the last hours of your visa will be considered your fault.

@MarkJohnson: So what do you think would have happened if my Beijing flight would have been delayed because of a technical defect instead of weather?  I'm pretty sure that would have played out the same way. What else could the Chinese do? Perhaps have everyone sleep in the airport departure area (which is technically still China)? Kick them out of the country? That's stupid too since everyone already WANTs to leave but they can't since there is no airplane. What other options are there?

@MarkJohnson weather events are not force majeure but Act of God, as the article you link to makes clear.  It notes that contractual clauses that deal with Force Majeure often also deal with Acts of God at the same time, but further notes that "such events remain legally distinct".

@Hilmar Make people pay a fine. Free money.

@MarkJohnson - Bad weather isn't "Force majeure" by any reasonably definition. Force majeure is war, natural disaster, etc. that's reasonably unforeseeable not just a bit of smog that makes it hard to fly in a place that is world renowned for smog.

@MadHatter from what I can tell from cursory googling, acts of God are a subclass force majeure, covering only the naturally caused instances. The term force majeure also covers events like wars, which are not acts of God. In e.g. the German legal tradition, there is no distinction, both are Höhere Gewalt.

Specifically for Thailand: In the event that your flight gets cancelled after you got an exit stamp, Thailand has no limits on how much foreigners can stay in a given timeframe (akin to Schengen's 90/180, or UK's 180/365), so if you ended up in border control to enter again, it is up to the border police if you get admitted into the country or not. There may be special cases for flight delays and cancellations though.

In most cases visa overstays will be evaluated case by case but countries (or groups of countries like Schengen) will have guidelines for the officers who have to deal with the cases.
And there might well be different guidelines between different kinds of visa, even within one country for people of one other country.
It is known that some countries have very strict rules while others are less strict.
Usually an overstay beyond your control is deemed less bad and while you often have to apply for an extension of the visa before it expires even that is not a given.
